# How to add LOG4CPP in my C++ project visual studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, log4cpp

I'm new with C++, after some research i want to add LOG4CPP to my current project and i really don't know where to begin. i downloaded the LOG4CPP package and i don't know what's next. i'm working on windows and using visual studio 2012, can someone please help me ?

Comment: Have you consulted the [FAQ](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/#faq)?

Comment: i don't know how to add the libraries in my visual studio project, and where to put the property file. i normaly work with maven in my java project and adding log4j has always be too easy, now with log4CPP in C++ project i did not know where to begin